# SQL query Takes Too much Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am reading a lot of data from 5 files at a time each file has 100,000 records, it takes too much time while inserting it into a table using a SQL query. Is there any way that insertion into the table take's less time?

My SQL query is

```
comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO try(DistrictName, TownName, FarmerName, Area, VarietyOfCrop) " + 
                      "VALUES(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5)", con);

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",DataTokenz[0]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", DataTokenz[1]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", DataTokenz[2]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", DataTokenz[3]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", DataTokenz[4]);
```

Comment: Try using Bulk Insert or Sql Bcp

Comment: You're using a super turbo slow method (RBAR)

Comment: Besides everything else mentioned, I would also recommend to use **more meaningful** names for your parameters - more meaningful than `@p1`, `@p2` and so on ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting row by row is very expensive & bad idea.

You can use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) or [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) (you will need bulkadmin permissions).

**As stated in MSDN documentation:**
*There are other ways to load data into a SQL Server table (INSERT statements, for example), but SqlBulkCopy offers a significant performance advantage over them.*